# Проблема с кодом МАССИВ c#

Tags: c#, матрицы

Дано квадратная матрица порядка n с целыми элементами. Найти наименьшее из значений элементов столбик, сумма модулей элементов которого является наибольшей. Если таких столбцов существует несколько, то взять первый Из них
Я пытался сделать но не получаеться я не знаю что делать дальше

```
cs
using System;
namespace ЛАБ_2_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("\n_______________________________");
            int[][] Mymass = new int[5][];
          

            Mymass[0] = new int[4];
            Mymass[1] = new int[4];
            Mymass[2] = new int[4];
            Mymass[3] = new int[4];

            int[][] Mymass2 = new int[4][];
            Mymass2[0] = new int[4];
            Mymass2[1] = new int[4];
            Mymass2[2] = new int[4];
            Mymass2[3] = new int[4];
            int [] Mymass3 = new int[4];
            
            int i, j,  min, max;
            int s = 0;
            int nomax = 0;



            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {

                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                    Mymass[i][j] = rand.Next(0, 10);
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {

                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                    Mymass2[j][i] = Mymass[i][j];
                    Console.Write(Mymass[i][j]);
                    Console.Write("    ");
                }
            }


            Console.Write("\n___________________________________");

            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                    Console.Write(Mymass[i][j]);
                    Console.Write("    ");
                }
            }


            Console.Write("\n___________________________________");
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    s = (Math.Abs(Mymass2[i][j]))  + s;
                   
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\ns||");           
                Mymass3[i] = s;
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                s = 0;               
            }
            Console.Write("\n___________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine(Mymass3 [0]);
            max = Mymass3[3];
            for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (max < Mymass3[i])
                {
                    max = Mymass3[i];
                    Console.WriteLine(max);
                }
               
             
            }
            Console.Write("\n___________________________________");
            for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (max < Mymass3[i])
                {
                    nomax = i;
                    
                   
                    Console.WriteLine(nomax);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
namespace ЛАБ_2_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("\n_______________________________");
            int[][] Mymass = new int[5][];


            Mymass[0] = new int[4];
            Mymass[1] = new int[4];
            Mymass[2] = new int[4];
            Mymass[3] = new int[4];

            int[][] Mymass2 = new int[4][];
            Mymass2[0] = new int[4];
            Mymass2[1] = new int[4];
            Mymass2[2] = new int[4];
            Mymass2[3] = new int[4];
            int[] Mymass3 = new int[4];

            int min, max;
            int s = 0;
            int nomax = 0;



            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                    Mymass[i][j] = rand.Next(0, 10);
                }
            }




            Console.Write("\n___________________________________");

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                    Console.Write(Mymass[i][j]);
                    Console.Write("  ");
                }
            }


            Console.Write("\n___________________________________");

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                    Mymass2[i][j] = Mymass[j][i];

                }
            }

            Console.Write("\n___________________________________");

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                   Console.Write(Mymass2[i][j]);
                    Console.Write("  ");
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n___________________________________");
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    s = (Math.Abs(Mymass2[i][j])) + s;

                }

                Mymass3[i] = s;

                s = 0;
            }
            Console.Write("\n___________________________________");

            max = Mymass3[0];
            nomax = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (max < Mymass3[i])
                {
                    max = Mymass3[i];
                    nomax = i;
                }


            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; 4 > i; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.Write(Mymass3[i]);
            }
            Console.Write("\n__________max____________________");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.WriteLine(nomax);




            min = Mymass2[nomax][0];
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {


                if (min > Mymass2[nomax][j])
                {
                    min = Mymass2[nomax][j];

                }


            }
            Console.Write("\n__________min____________________");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.WriteLine(min);
        }
    }
}
```

решил проблему подобным образом